# Detect when AVPlayerViewController is closed

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

From a table view cell, I play video from a url:

```
        let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/MI201109210084_1/m3u8s/f08e80da-bf1d-4e3d-8899-f0f6155f6efa.m3u8")!)
        player.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = false

        let vc = AVPlayerViewController()
        vc.player = player

        // Loop video
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player.currentItem, queue: .main) { [weak self] _ in
            player.seek(to: CMTime.zero)
            player.play()
        }

        self.parentViewController.present(vc, animated: true, completion: {
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                vc.player?.playImmediately(atRate: 1.0)
            } else {
                vc.player?.play()
            }
        })
```

How can I detect when the `AVPlayerViewController` is closed/dismissed? I want to do something when it's closed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no specific `delegate` or `notification` that I know of for when the AVPlayerViewController is dismissed.

However, you could try the following steps since you present the `AVPlayerViewController`

**1. Conformance to the UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate**

Make the `UIViewController` that `presents` the **AVPlayerViewController** conform to the transitioning delegate

```
class YourVC: UIViewController, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate
```

**2. AVPlayerController SetUp**

Make the view controller presenting the `AVPlayerController` the `transitioningDelegate` of the `AVPlayerController`

```
let vc = AVPlayerViewController()

// Add this
vc.transitioningDelegate = self

vc.player = player
```

**3. Finally, implement the transition delegate function**

```
// MARK: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate
// Gets called when a modal was dismissed
func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController)
-> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning?
{
    // The dismissal was before the movie ended
    print("AVPlayerController dismissed")
    return nil
}
```

Give this a go and see if this helps